# Block acess for new devices on the LAN

Tags: parental-controls

I wanted my Parental Controls to control screen time for my son's PC.
I have set that up by his MAC Address which is tied to his IP.
But, I have seen that he can access the Wi-Fi using a random MAC address on his phone.

If he sets that up on his PC as well (connected to LAN), I'd like to deny access for any new devices that are not already known (whitelist).

How do I do that?
(RT-AX58U)

Comment: well, most of the time that requires configuring your wifi to only allow devices with known mac addresses to connect to the wifi. its not a particularly strong level of protection, and a smart kid can get around it, but that's about all you can do with a standard consumer-grade internet access router.

Comment: Some routers (my own Cisco RV series router) allows Access Times in the Firewall section and then allows access schedules in the System Configuration.  These can be combined to provide some level of user access security. Combine that with MAC address limitations and only allow yourself with access to the router.

Comment: check your router's manual.  you can usually limit by mac address.